# Fazendo breadcrumb de data-type de uma <li> ao descer a página

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Alguém pode me ajudar nisso.

Eu tenho a página e html que é uma lista gigante.

Cada < li> tem um um campo de data nele

```
<li class="classe_dia" data-dia="12">Conteúdo</li>
<li class="classe_dia" data-dia="13">Conteúdo</li>
<li class="classe_dia" data-dia="14">Conteúdo</li>
<li class="classe_dia" data-dia="15">Conteúdo</li>
```

Ao dar scroll na página gostaria de capturar o data-dia do elemento que estiver na altura 150px do $(window).scrollTop()

Codepen:
https://codepen.io/alemoraesra/pen/eXjdyx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
   var $topOffset = [],
 $section = $('.classe_dia');

$(window).resize(function() {
  $topOffset = [];
  $.each($section, function() {
$topOffset.push($(this).offset().top);
  });
}).trigger('resize');

$(window).scroll(function() {
var $browserTop = $(window).scrollTop();

$.each($section, function(i) {
 if (($browserTop >= $topOffset[i]) && ($browserTop < $topOffset[i] + $(this).height())) {
  var result = $(this).attr('data-dia');
 $('#resultado').text(result);

 }
});
}).trigger('scroll');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li class="classe_dia" data-dia="12">Conteúdo</li>
<li class="classe_dia" data-dia="13">Conteúdo</li>
<li class="classe_dia" data-dia="14">Conteúdo</li>
<li class="classe_dia" data-dia="15">Conteúdo</li>
```

Com esse script eu pego o valor do elemento LI que estiver na mesma altura do scrollTop. Espero ter lhe ajudado!

Comment: Olá João Victor, eu quero fazer um breadcrumb de uma lista que eu tenho, eu tentei reproduzir neste codepen https://codepen.io/alemoraesra/pen/eXjdyx, não deu bem certo, depois que chega no fim ele não altera mais

Comment: Opa. Consegui resolver, o novo código ta no mesmo lugar de antes